# Jquerymobile: Highlight a word in paragraph and give a click event

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

In my jquery+phonegap app the screen is filled with Text(paragraph) now i want to highlight some of the words in the paragraph and give a click event to it, and also a popup explaining the particular word.How can i achieve this. please share some ideas.

Comment: Are you stuck anywhere?

Comment: just put a <span /> around the words of interest and add highlight css and a click event.

Comment: @Omar i need a popup when i click on the span element, not a full page dailog.

Comment: @Omar i did this $('.WordSpan').click(function() {
    alert("hi");
    
}); but how to get a popup

Comment: @Omar tried this too $('#Match').delegate('span.WordSpan', 'click', function() {
    alert($(this).html());
    
});     in browser it is working but in mobile its not.

Comment: this way http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/JYLRK/

Comment: @Omar hey thanx a lot can i customise the pop up color and put custom text in it?

Comment: You can, play around with it. When you're stuck, let me know ;)

Comment: @Omar hey i have different text to show for each hilite word..and in different pages ...can u please let me know how to implement it?

Comment: the example above shows how you can add new "word" to popup. Inside a popup, there's a placeholder for a word, add "word" to it and then open popup.

Comment: @Omar i am able to add new text but how to give different text to different highlighted words?